# WTForms, populating fields from POST but omitting some

Tags: wtforms

What's the easiest way to populate fields when doing

```
form.populate_obj(user)
```

but without populating fields that are specified via a dictionary of removable fields, such as ['subscription','subscriptionterm']?

Does wtforms support this natively? I skimmed through the wtforms quickly, but alas haven't been able to find anything conclusive.

Would this be better handled if Form was subclassed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if request.method == "POST" and form.validate_on_submit():
            # populate all field == wtforms obj
            form.populate_obj(user)
            # insert specificaly data field
            user.some_field_not_populate = form.some_field_not_populate.data
            # save change obj in database
            user.save()
```

or other way  -  make mixin class.